# Get IBM "Virtual Server for Classic" prices from IBM Global Catalog API

Tags: api, cloud, ibm-cloud

Following is the link from IBM which display prices of "Virtual Servers for Classic" for different instances and locations.

https://cloud.ibm.com/gen1/infrastructure/provision/vs

I would like to get the same prices from IBM Global Catalog API , but I cannot find any prices in the API. Following is the link for IBM Global Catalog API

https://globalcatalog.cloud.ibm.com/update/virtual-server-group?noLocations=true

what exactly, I am missing here. Any leads will be great.

Answer (score 1):

I'm very confident that that isn't exposed. The prices are different per region and per resource options available. And the chance of that being added is low due to the focus on VPCs and the Gen 2 backends.

Take a look [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/vpc/latest) the new VPC API and the coverage, though looking deeper I don't see an API for price reporting either.